# XQuery 3.0 "group by" with multiple keys

Tags: group-by, xquery

I can get results the results I want without using "group by", which makes my inability to do that with "group by" all the more frustrating. Supposing I want to group plays according to whether they have speakers with the same name, so that for a corpus of plays, I can return each unique speaker name (within the entire corpus) and the number of plays in which a speaker of that name appears. For example, if "Angel" appears in three plays, I would get a group keyed to "Angel" and the group would contain those three plays. When I try the following in eXist (never mind the counting or the sorting parts of the problem for the moment):

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";
let $plays := collection('/db/apps/shakespeare/data')
for $play in $plays
group by $sp := $play//tei:speaker
return $sp
```

I get the following error: "Compilation Error. err:XPTY0004 More that one key values [at line 5, column 18, source: String]" I understand that plays have multiple speakers; what I haven't been able to crack is how to say "Assign each play to multiple groups, that is, to one group for each speaker in that play. Plays that contains speakers with the same name will wind up in the same groups." Advice welcome.

Comment: well, that's not how group by works. Group by assigns one element to strictly one group. In your case, I would collect all distinct speakers and in an inner for loop collect all plays which belong to the designated speaker. For a more concrete XQuery example, we would need your XML data.

Comment: data is at <https://github.com/wolfgangmm/ShakespeareDemo/tree/master/data>

Comment: Thank you both for the quick response. I already have a working solution using dirkk's approach, and my question wasn't about how to get the grouping as about how to do it using "group by". The information that "group by" doesn't work the way I thought it did is therefore very helpful, so thanks again! For what it's worth, the misunderstanding arose because I thought "group by" would work the way grouping works in XSLT.